# Looking for an additional feature - Cross site lookup field

Tags: development, lookup-column

We want to implement the cross site lookup in our environment and decided to use the solution available at http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com.

Unfortunately, there is a missing feature that should be implemented. It should be able to display multiple columns of the original list (where the value of the lookup field is stored) in the view of the target list (where the lookup column is used) like the standard sharepoint lookup does.

Have you ever worked on such a requirement? If so, any help.

Answer (score 2):

a coworker of mine has written LookUpFieldWithPicker which is part of ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com . It supports cross site lookups.

Comment: Give him/her (coworker) my best regards!

Comment: :D No problem...

Answer (score 0):

there are also some 3-rd party tools that allow you to add cross site lookup feature. I know that boostsolutions and arfulbits have such component.

Comment: Do we have any native SharePoint solution to it?